# Making 3D wireframes Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am tring to create a 3D wireframe using the 'mesh' command in matlab.

Specifically, I have the following points:

```
{1,1,1}

{2,2,2}

{3,3,3}

{4,4,4}
```

I assume by connecting them they should form a quadrilateral with angles pointing to such points.

My code:

```
mesh([[1;1;1;1] [2;2;2;2] [3;3;3;3]]);
```

Which results in:

[image]

Which leaves me quite confused... why is my y-axis extending beyond 3? Also, is this the kind of result I should expect? I find it a bit hard to validate my work in a 2D projection of a 3D shape.

Comment: You are passing a matrix to `mesh`,  which is interpreted as `z` values of the points, with `x` and `y` being implicitly `1:4`. What is the result you want to obtain?

Comment: @LuisMendo well I'd expect a point at x=1,y=1,z=1 one at x=2,y=2,z=2 etc

Comment: [`mesh`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mesh.html) might not be doing what you expect. It is taking the 4x3 matrix `[[1;1;1;1] [2;2;2;2] [3;3;3;3]]` to represent a function lying over a 4x3 grid in the x-y plane, then plotting the value of the matrix as a height above the x-y plane.

Comment: Assuming your points represent (x,y,z) coordinates of each point, isn't your points lie in one line? Second, why you use only 3 points to plot, instead of using all your 4 points?

Comment: It would be possible to do this with Delaunay triangulation if your points weren't collinear, you've simply a line in 3D space, which you could plot using the `plot3` or  `quiver3` functions.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to answer your question as your question is impossible. You have four points on a 3D line. To visualise them on a plot, try this:

```
x = [1;2;3;4];

plot3(x,x,x);
```